# Why do javascript variables in closure functions not reset to a default when called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, closures, scope

In the code below please can someone explain to me why multiple calls to `counter` result in the value of `i` increasing each time it is called?

My understanding is that as we specifically set `i = 0;` in `makeCounter`, each time `makeCounter` is called through the `counter` variable, `i` should be reset to 0. I cannot understand why this is not the case.

```
function makeCounter() {
  // `i` is only accessible inside `makeCounter`.
  var i = 0;

  return function() {
    console.log( ++i );
  };
}

// Note that `counter` and `counter2` each have their own scoped `i`.

var counter = makeCounter();
counter(); // logs: 1
counter(); // logs: 2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> each time makeCounter is called through the "counter" variable

That is wrong.

You're only calling `makeCounter()` **once** – at `var counter = makeCounter();`.
`counter` is a reference to the *returned function*, which closes over the `i` variable.

Calling `counter()` will execute this returned function, just like any other function.

The behavior you're expecting would happen if you write `makeCounter()()` multiple times.

Comment: I see, so the returned function from makeCounter is the only part that is executed and not the declaration of i=0. If the Function that was returned was the following..

 return function() {
    i = 0;
    console.log( ++i );
  };

Then 'i' would only ever equal 1, is that correct?

Comment: @BenMillane, yes. If you want to see exactly what is invoked when you do `counter()`, why not `console.log(counter)`

Answer (score 1):

> each time makeCounter is called […] `i` should be reset to `0`

That's right.

> `makeCounter` is called through the `counter` variable

No it's not. The anonymous function returned by `makeCounter` is called with `counter()`. `makeCounter` was only called once, its *result* was assigned to the `counter` variable.

> Note that `counter` and `counter2` each have their own scoped `i`

That would be the case, yes. However your example is incomplete:

```
var counter = makeCounter();
counter(); // logs 1
var counter2 = makeCounter();
counter2(); // logs 1 again!
counter(); // still logs 2
counter2(); // logs 2
```

Comment: Right, sorry yes the example is incomplete, I copied just the part that I was focused on. The rest of the example was similar to what you have shown.

I understand now, I didn't pay proper attention to what was being returned from the makeCounter variable and how it was being accessed. This is what 4 days off coding does to you!